# How to traverse json tree(dictionary) in parallel way using python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parallel-processing

```
{ 
  'A':
     {
       'a':[],
       'aa':val
     },
  'B':
     { 
       'b':[],
       'bb':val
     },
  'C':
     {
       'c':[],
       'cc':val
     }
}
```

Suppose this tree has thousand branches like 'A', 'B', 'C'. It's easy to traverse and search one by one from 'A' to 'C' which consumes a lot of time.`

So I want to traverse and search 'val' at once in A, B, C branches in any kind of parallel way.

Comment: It is unlikely that there could be a speed up in traversing a dictionary by parallelization, but you haven't given any details. How big is the json? What do you consider to be "a lot of time""? Have you measured it, it do you just think it is slow? Is the traversal slow, or some process done after the traversal (which actually might be worth parallelizing)?

Comment: The tree contains about 120k keys. If I traverse every branch and access every value in a  single thread it takes around  0.8291sec and if I do any process like matching value then in the worst case it takes about 5sec which is a lot. That's why I'm searching a way to reduce time by any parallelism way

Comment: So, it takes < 1 sec to traverse the dictionary and then 4 seconds to do something with the data. It looks like you should optimise the 4 seconds and not the < 1 sec. How exactly to do that depends on what kind of logic you do, whether you do it only once per data set or more times etc. Anyway, it seems that the question about parallelizing dictionary traversal is a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can speed it up with parallelization, but in case you have a lot of keys, you can use [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) to try and make it faster:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def parallel_process(key):
   return your_function(your_dict[key])

result = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(parallel_process)(key) for key in your_dict.keys())
```

The result will be a list, if you want to change a common variable you also can. For example define a result dict and add keys and values inside the parallel function.

Your question does not say what you want the end result to be, but the above solution is a great start.

You should play around and see if it's actually make it faster, but generally speaking my intuition says that you have to have a very "heavy" `your_function` to make it worth it, as well as an enormous amounts of keys.

Comment: Thanks for your response @dr-prof-patrick. Let me check how it works!

Comment: Hey, it took 0.0002772sec for a single thread to traverse the whole tree but when I used Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(parallel_process)(key) for key in DSUTASS.keys()) it took around 0.63634991sec. Am I missing something?

Comment: that's what i meant when i said i doubt you will get a speedup using parallelization for iterating the tree. the processing you do for each branch has to be really heavy for it to be worthwhile. Imagine all i want to do is add 2 numbers (very fast), the amount of energy i will use to distribute the jobs will far exceed the amount of work i actually need to do.

Comment: also from your other comment you said it took takes 0.83 seconds to 5 seconds to traverse the entire thing so it actually does speed your end result, no?

Comment: The speed up from 1 s to  0.0002772 s sounds like either wrong measurement, or no traversal was done in the second case (lazy traversal?)